# Cancel Thread Sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

I have a simple Console application with 2 running threads.

The first thread is measuring some values, and the second thread looks for user input and performs some mouse movements.

```
while (true)
{
    if (Input.IsKeyDown(VC_L))
    {
        Mouse.Move(300, 500);
        Thread.Sleep(thread1_delay);
        Mouse.Move(670, 300);
        Thread.Sleep(thread1_delay);
        Mouse.Move(870, 700);
        Thread.Sleep(thread1_delay);
    }
}
```

The problem is I want to stop the second thread as soon as I get another key as input. But it's not working since the thread is still sleeping and doesn't react.

Comment: One options is to use `Task.Delay`, and a `CancellationToken`

Comment: If you need to cancel the sleep you should not be using Thread.Sleep, you should be using tasks and cancellation tokens. To answer your question, you can use `Thread.Interrupt` to wake it up from the current/next sleep, but this is like answering the question "How can I shoot off my food without it hurting" with "Take painkillers"

Comment: I thinks you can use Thread's Abort method

Comment: @RamilAliyev using `Thread.Abort` to anything is almost certainly the wrong approach

Comment: @MichaelRandall why? Please give me information )

Comment: @RamilAliyev have *Eric Lippert* instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/1612975

Comment: Thread.Interrupt and Thread.Abort is both wrong answers. The correct answer is that you shouldn't try to cancel a Thread.Sleep, instead you should use something else that can be cancelled. If you don't want/can't use tasks, use a WaitHandle, like ManualResetEvent, and wait for it with the given timeout. When the timeout occurs, the wait is over, or if you signal the handle, the wait is over.

Comment: Thread.Sleep() is not the problem, it is finite.  It is `while (true)` that's the problem, that one is infinite.

Comment: You are handling keyboard events and doing something in regular intervals. Maybe you should consider an event based approach (handling "OnKeyDown/Up" and "Timer_Elapsed").

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8) and be done with it

> Propagates notification that operations should be canceled.

**Example**

```
public static async Task DoFunkyStuff(CancellationToken token)
{
   // a logical escape for the loop
   while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      try
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
         await Task.Delay(1000, token);
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled");
      }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

**Usage**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

   var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

   Console.WriteLine("Press key to cancel tasks");
   var task = DoFunkyStuff(ts.Token);

   // user input
   Console.ReadKey();

   Console.WriteLine("Cancelling token");

   // this is how to cancel
   ts.Cancel();

   // just to prove the task has been cancelled
   await task;

   // because i can
   Console.WriteLine("Elvis has left the building");
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Results**

```
Press key to cancel tasks
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Cancelling token
Task Cancelled
Finished
Elvis has left the building
```

Answer (score 0):

The second thread should check for a Boolean value when it wakes up. You should set this value to false when your condition is met. Now when the second thread wakes up it will complete it's execution.